# qbo3 Rendering data from API calls

Tags: html-table, qbo3

I am using qbo3 to fetch data from our data warehouse (`Process/MyApiCall?Foo=Bar`), and I'd like to display the data to an end user. Does qbo3 have a standard UI for such data (without knowing the schema in advance)?

Answer (score 0):

qbo3 contains `Templates/Report/Standard.xslt` that will render a `DataTable` or `DataReader` as an HTML table.

To view the API data in raw HTML format:

```
// View as XML
Process/MyApiCall?Foo=Bar&Output=Xml

// View as JSON
Process/MyApiCall?Foo=Bar&Output=Json

// View as an HTML table
Process/MyApiCall?Foo=Bar&Transform=Templates/Report/Standard.xslt
```

To wrap this same output in the standard QBO skin:

```
Theme.ashx/Wrap?ClassName=Process&Method=MyApiCall&Foo=Bar&Transform=Templates/Report/Standard.xslt
```

---

The `Standard.xslt` will render a `<table>` for each `DataTable` returned by the API call, and a `<th>` for each column returned in a `DataTable`.

If the columns follow standard QBO convention with `{Table}ID` / `{Table}` paired next to each other, QBO will combine these results into a single column, displaying `{Table}` with a hyperlink to the underlying record. Note that this feature only works with QBO-recognized `Modules` (found in Configuration > Modules).